# Unexpected use of 'event' getting value of an icon. (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the value of my icon but it says that event is deprecated.

```
const TaskContainer = (props) => {
function handleChange(event){ 
        alert(event.target.value);
    }

return (
 <i className='bx bx-add-to-queue bx-tada-hover' value={props.columnname.id} onClick={handleChange(event)} ></i>
)
}
```

Comment: Just change (event) as (e) and mention it as "e" where ever you use "event", this might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to write like this:

```
onClick={event => handleChange(event)}
```

Or that way:

```
onClick={handleChange}
```

Comment: Still returned undefined. But when i console.log "event.target" it shows the element with the value. https://i.ibb.co/zNr8cBR/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function, instead you should do this-

```
<i className='bx bx-add-to-queue bx-tada-hover' value={props.columnname.id} onClick={handleChange} ></i>
```

or,

```
<i className='bx bx-add-to-queue bx-tada-hover' value={props.columnname.id} onClick={(event) => handleChange(event)} ></i>
```

Please have a look at [handling events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for better understanding of how event handlers should be put up in react.

Comment: I tried the first one and it returned undefined, the second code shows  an error  "Unexpected use of 'event'". I inspected the value of the icon and it shows the data.

Comment: icons dont have value attribute on them.
can you please help me in understanding what you're trying to achieve, as anyways you'll have access to props.columnname.id in your handler.